# Export DynamoDB data to S3 and get the presigned url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

While I have alternative to write a lambda for this where I can do,

```
def lambda_handler:
   file = scan_db_and_push_data_in_csv()
   s3_client.upload(file)
   return s3_client_get_presigned_url()
```

But here I will be needing to do scan, and also I searched for other ways of exporting those are mostly manual or non-programmatical. The lambda code will get triggered on button click. Is there any better way to this.

While I have a idea that we can use a AWS Datapipeline for the use case. But can we get a pre-signed url for the CSV upload in that case. I am not able to decide which approach I should use.

Option 1: Use Lambda and do a scan and upload.
Option 2: Trigger data pipeline through code and generate presigned url from s3 once data is uploaded in s3.

Resources I have looked:

[DynamoDB export to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054868/dynamo-db-export-to-csv)

[Data Pipeline - DynamoDB export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244681/data-pipeline-dynamo-db-export)

[Exporting and Importing DynamoDB Data Using AWS Data Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.html)

Comment: You can export the data to s3 bucket using `export_table_to_point_in_time`. it will not be a CSV export though.

Comment: Can this be triggered using an api call, or is it scheduled?

Comment: However you want.

Comment: Do you have any code pointers handy for this